# I can't set the limit that the contract accumulates tokens to exchange for BNB

Tags: pancakeswap, forks

My contract is a safemoon fork. He must tax transactions, accumulate some tokens and sell these tokens by BNB to send to the 4 wallets in the code. Turns out he must sell the tokens when he hits a limit and he's not doing that. Although the contract is exchanged for BNB, I don't know the amount he uses for the exchange. I would like to set a limit for it to switch, because the contract accumulates a very large amount of tokens.

How to solve this?

https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x321c548b779d2e94cfdfa26fdb5cbb8e421abac5#writeContract

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Line 1071: `bool overMinTokenBalance = contractTokenBalance >= numTokensSellToAddToLiquidity;` this is the a test done on each transfer, checking if the contract token balance is >= to 'numTokensSellToAddToLiquidity'. This is therefore the variable you're looking for (and it's setter function is line 948 `setNumTokensSellToAddToLiquidityPercent(...)`, with an onlyOwner modifier).

If you check what's happening when this test returns true a few lines later, the function swapAndLiquify is called (Ln1079). This function is taking the whole token balance from the contract, splitting it in 2 halves:

- swapping one half for BNB's which is then split in 5: 4/5 are sent to 4 addresses while the 1/5 left serves to add liquidity to the pool
- the other half is serves for the liquidity too.

The pool ratio is not checked after the swap and the liquidity transfer is suboptimal (fixed at a 1/5 BNB/Token)

Comment: Your explanation was excellent, it made me understand more about the contract. Would replacing "numTokensSellToAddToLiquidity" with a fixed value solve the sale limit issue? When the tokens reach this value the contract sells. Turns out I interacted with the setNumTokensSellToAddToLiquidityPercent function, but the contract isn't selling when it hits the value, even though it's a very small amount.

Comment: In other words, the contract must sell to BNB whenever it reaches the value and this should be independent of the transfer.

Comment: “Independent of the transfer” is impossible, you need a contract interaction in first place! Pay attention to how swap() in uniswap works (esp “LOK”) -> tl;dr you can have you “extra swap” when selling token, not buying (to avoid reentrancy)